# Possible ways of choosing 7 courses out of 20 with the constraint that at least 1 course has to be a stat course

Tags: combinatorics

To fulfill the requirements for a certain degree, a student can choose to take any $7$ out of a list of $20$ courses, with the constraint that at least $1$ of the $7$ courses must be a statistics course. Suppose that $5$ of the $20$ courses are statistics courses.

(a) How many choices are there for which 7 courses to take?

The solution I believe is : $$\binom{5}{1}\binom{15}{6} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{15}{5} + \binom{5}{3}\binom{15}{4} + \binom{5}{4}\binom{15}{3} + \binom{5}{5}\binom{15}{2}$$
But the solution seems to be $$\binom{20}{7} - \binom{15}{7}$$
I evaluated the two expressions and they give different numerical values.
I want to know where am I going wrong.

The question was earlier asked in the following link:
[Take seven courses out of 20 with requirement](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1213185/811099)

Comment: Both expressions evaluate to $71085$.

Comment: You may have some calculation mistakes. They have to be the same.

Comment: Ohh yeah...it does....so my approach is not incorrect?

Comment: Your approach is correct.  To properly format $\binom{n}{k}$, type `$\binom{n}{k}$` or, in display mode, `$$\binom{n}{k}$$`.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers are equal and both correct.

The relationship between the answers is explained by [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)

$$\binom{m+n}{r}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^r\binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{r-k}$$

In your case, that is $$\binom{20}{7}=\binom{5}{0}\binom{15}{7}+\binom{5}{1}\binom{15}{6}+\binom{5}{2}\binom{15}{5}+\dots+\binom{5}{5}\binom{15}{2}\color{grey}{+\binom{5}{6}\binom{15}{1}+\binom{5}{7}\binom{15}{0}}$$

The terms at the end were zero and so can be discarded.  Then, by subtracting the $\binom{5}{0}\binom{15}{7}$ term from both sides and evaluating $\binom{5}{0}$ as $1$ you are left with $$\binom{20}{7}-\binom{15}{7}=\binom{5}{1}\binom{15}{6}+\dots+\binom{5}{5}\binom{15}{2}$$

Arguably, the expression on the left is easier to work with since there are less terms and less arithmetic involved, but both are equally correct.